# keep statements next to each other while formatting the code

Tags: java, android-studio, settings, android-studio-3.0, code-formatting

I tend to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to reformat my code  when im done coding but i dont want to break lines where i write statements next to each other.

this should remain as it is.

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); assert actionBar != null;
```

but this should break the line.

```
{ foo();
```

is there option for that?

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but can you refactor it to `ActionBar actionBar = assertNotNull(getSupportActionBar());`?

Comment: cant find that method, my minSdkVersion is 15 btw

Comment: write the method.

Comment: @AndyTurner found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

```
Settings
  Editor
    Code Style
      Java
        Wrapping and Braces
          Keep when reformatting
            Multiple expressions in one line <= tick this
```